# Fusing cross-correlated measurements for mobile robot's localization using unscented kalman filter (ukf)

Tags: mobile-robot, localization, kalman-filter, sensor-fusion, lidar

I'm currently working on a mobile robot's indoor localization. On the perception side, I can only rely on a 2D lidar and wheel odometry.

I have used these sources as input of different localization's packages such as [slam_toolbox](https://github.com/SteveMacenski/slam_toolbox), an icp based package that does scan-to-map matching and a landmark detector.
They all give interesting outputs but for the landmark detector and the scan-to-map matcher, the results are sporadic.

I would like to fuse all the estimated positions into a more reliable one and therefore tried to use [robot_localization's ukf](http://docs.ros.org/en/noetic/api/robot_localization/html/state_estimation_nodes.html#ukf-localization-node) implementation to do so.
For those familiar with ros, I am trying to find the tf between odom and map based on the results of all these packages.

The problem is, all these results are based on cross-correlated measurements and this might affect the convergence of the filter.

**Is it possible to fuse results based on the same input sources ?**

If yes, is ukf a right way to do so ?

Otherwise, are there other filters more adapted to this application ?

Thank you in advance for your help !

Comment: Sorry, can you clarify what you mean by "Is it possible to fuse results based on the same input sources?". What input sources would you like to feed to the UKF?